# How to enforce edit suggestions of a post to require approval from the author of the post?

Tags: 7

I'm creating a user community site and one of the features is to reward points to registered users.

One feature I'm trying to implement is to reward points for every edit on a post only if the author accepts the edit, the user who submitted the edit should get a point only if the edit is accepted by the author of the post.

How would I implement this in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 2):

Try [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints)

> This module provides an API for users to gain or lose points for
>   performing certain actions on your site.
>
> In conjunction with other modules, such as the Userpoints Nodes and
>   Comments users can accumulate points for actions such as posting
>   nodes, commenting or moderation duties.
>
> Use one of the many contributed modules to extend the functionality of
>   the module to include point accumulation on page views or votes,
>   upgrade roles based on point balance, or purchase goods from your
>   store.

And if you need to do states of content, try [Workflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow)

> This module allows you to create arbitrary Workflows, and assign them
>   to Entities.
>
> Workflows are made up of workflow states. Transitions between states
>   can be allowed per role. For example, **a workflow with the states
>   *Draft*, *Review*, and *Published*** could be assigned to the Story node type.
>   Only users with role 'chief editor' can set Stories to the published
>   state. You can set up the Workflow to alter states from form, page,
>   comment and a special workflow tab.
>
> Transitions between workflow states can have actions assigned to them.
>   In our example, we could assign an action so that when the story moves
>   from the Draft state to the Review state an email is sent out. Another
>   action could be assigned to the transition from Review to Published so
>   that the node's status is set to Published (and becomes visible on
>   your website).

Answer (score 1):

## Step 1 - Add workflow

Use the [Workflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow) module to manage the suggested edit before it actually get published. Here are some typical values you may want to use for the actual workflow management:

- Draft
- Needs review
- Needs work
- Needs author approval **(1)**
- Published

**(1)**: Feel free to use what fits for your case, but make sure to include "a" value like "***Needs author approval***" (or something similar to that), which will be used to collect the author's approval.

## Step 2 - Verify author approval

Use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to check if, for "Needs author approval", it is the posts's author who is actually attempting to change the status to "Published". For any other user trying to do so, issue a Rules Action to just set an appropriate Drupal error (not just warning) message, indicating that only the post author can change the status to published (which is like a final approve). If the approve is indeed given by the post author, then assign the appropriate [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) (also via [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)).

You can implement this as 2 separated rules, or if you also use the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module you can combine them both in a single rule.